# Number Theory Problem: Pseudoprimes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I want to prove the following:

> If the number $M_p=2^p-1$ is composite, where $p$ is a prime, then $M_p$ is a pseudoprime.

I know the following facts:

- A composite integer $n$ is called *pseudoprime* whenever $n|2^n-2$.
- Because $n$ is a composite number, we can write $n=rs$, with $1<r\le s<n$. Then, $2^r-1|2^n-1$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi! The question is prove that Mp is a pseudoprime. Thank you for your help!

Comment: ... *if* Mp is composite, that is.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q$ be a prime dividing $M_p$. Then $2^p-1$ is divisible by $q$, and hence the order of $2$ mod $q$, which is $p$, must divide $q-1$. That is: $p|(q-1)$.

Therefore, we have: $2^p-1|2^{(q-1)}-1$, i.e. $2^q \equiv 2$ (mod $M_p$).
Let $k$ be the highest power of $q$ that divides $M_p$. Repeatedly apply the above congruence $k$ times, then raise both sides to every prime power that divides $M_p$: the R.H.S. is still 2, the L.H.S. is $2^{M_p}$.

Thus, we get $2^{M_p} \equiv 2$ (mod $M_p$).

Comment: Thank you for your help! May you explain more how do you convert 2^q = 2 (mod Mp) to 2^Mp = 2 (mod Mp)?

Comment: May you tell me why in the R.H.S. is still 2, after you raise the power?